# Syntax for creating a pointer to member function

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compile an old code that uses pointers to (non-static) member functions, but it won't compile because the syntax is different now. I can only create a pointer to a function `Foo` by typing `&Bar::Foo`, which didn't use to be the case (simply typing `Foo` would create a member pointer).

When was this syntax added and is there a way to allow the old syntax in VisualStudio to avoid modifying the old code?

Here's a random example, which *used* to compile:

```
class Foo
{
public:
  int Bar(int x)
  {
    return x + 2;
  }

  Foo();
};
int (Foo::*f)(int);
Foo::Foo()
{
  f = Bar; // error, have to use f = &Foo::Bar now
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code in question?

Comment: I know the difference between normal and member function pointers, I'm specifically asking about the (new) syntax for creating member pointers. Adding a code sample.

Comment: There isn't any "new" syntax... unless you're going back to the mid-90s before C++ was even standardised...

Answer (score 3):

You don't specify in your question, but whenever I hear the words "the syntax is different," I assume you are migrating from Visual C++ 6 to a newer version of Visual Studio.

The long and short of it is; Visual C++ 6 does not use "standards-compliant C++."  Migrating from Visual C++ 6 to *any* other modern compiler will cause many syntax errors, and will take some effort to migrate into "compliance."  You'll just have to suck it up and make the syntax changes.

**Off-hand; I don't have a source to back me up, but I would be willing to bet that your function pointer syntax falls into this category.**

The good news is; once you've done it, pretty much all the rest of the modern compilers in the world will work with standards-compliant code, so you should only ever have to do this once.

**Update:**

I did a quick search and found at [least one source](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible) which seems to confirm the MSVC6 behavior:

> "Some compilers (most notably MSVC 6 and 7) will let you omit the &, even though it is non-standard and confusing. More standard-compliant compilers (e.g., GNU G++ and MSVC 8 (a.k.a. VS 2005)) require it, so you should definitely put it in."

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to use the standards compliant syntax for the type of, for creating and for calling member function pointers. VC++6 was more generous; e.g. when you wanted to create a function pointer you don't need to name the class it's in, unless ambiguous; that's simply not possible in standard C++.

---

The **type** of member function pointer to a function like

```
int Bar::Foo(int x);
```

is

```
int (Bar::*)(int)
```

and with a name (e.g. a variable or parameter of this type):

```
int (Bar::*function)(int)
```

---

To **create** a member function pointer you *have* to use the ampersand operator:

```
function = &Bar::Foo;
```

---

To **call** such a function you need the following syntax (assuming `bar` is a `Bar*`):

```
(bar->*function)(42);
```

or (if `bar` is a `Bar`):

```
(bar.*function)(42);
```

or (if `bar` is a smart pointer to `Bar` implementing `operator*`):

```
((*bar).*function)(42);
```

Answer (score 1):

Following may help:

```
class A
{
public:
    void foo();
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    void (A::*mem_func)() = &A::foo;

    A a;

    (a.*mem_func)();

    return 0;
}
```